# Tracking change in value (specific change) between rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

Would like to do some tracking of changing values within a column between the rows.
I have a dataset which consist of vehicle, timestamp,mode(4 mode in 0,2,4,8)
e.g.

```
vehicle, timestamp, mode
x,1970-01-19 01:24:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:25:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:26:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:27:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:28:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:29:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:30:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:31:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:32:59.973, 0
```

I would like to track the change of mode, specifically when it change from 2 to 0. something like as shown below

```
vehicle, timestamp, mode, changes
x,1970-01-19 01:24:59.973, 0, NaN
x,1970-01-19 01:25:59.973, 2, NaN
x,1970-01-19 01:26:59.973, 2, NaN
x,1970-01-19 01:27:59.973, 0, 1
x,1970-01-19 01:28:59.973, 2, NaN
x,1970-01-19 01:29:59.973, 0, 1
x,1970-01-19 01:30:59.973, 0, NaN
x,1970-01-19 01:31:59.973, 2, NaN
x,1970-01-19 01:32:59.973, 0, 1
```

Please advice!

Answer (score 1):

No for loop or list comprehension required. Use [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html)

Input:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""vehicle, timestamp, mode
x,1970-01-19 01:24:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:25:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:26:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:27:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:28:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:29:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:30:59.973, 0
x,1970-01-19 01:31:59.973, 2
x,1970-01-19 01:32:59.973, 0""".replace(', ', ',')), sep=',', engine='python')
```

Adding new column 'changes' and fill with 1 when [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) is -2:

```
df.loc[(df['mode'].diff() == -2) & (df['mode'] == 0), 'changes'] = 1
```

Output:

```
  vehicle                timestamp  mode  changes
0       x  1970-01-19 01:24:59.973     0      NaN
1       x  1970-01-19 01:25:59.973     2      NaN
2       x  1970-01-19 01:26:59.973     2      NaN
3       x  1970-01-19 01:27:59.973     0      1.0
4       x  1970-01-19 01:28:59.973     2      NaN
5       x  1970-01-19 01:29:59.973     0      1.0
6       x  1970-01-19 01:30:59.973     0      NaN
7       x  1970-01-19 01:31:59.973     2      NaN
8       x  1970-01-19 01:32:59.973     0      1.0
```

Comment: that is a good way :) but two things, `df['changes'] = np.nan` is not necessary as with `df.loc...`, by defautlt, the rows not selecting by the condition will be `nan`, then the OP said the mode can be 0,2,4,8 and your condition would also select when it goes from 4 to 2 (if any in real dataset as not present in the example) while the OP wants to catch only from 2 to 0. So I think you need to add the condition that the row is 0 with the diff = -2 :)

Comment: then you got my +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ["vehicle", 'timestamp', 'mode']

rows = [["x","1970-01-19 01:24:59.973", 0],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:25:59.973", 2],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:26:59.973", 2],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:27:59.973", 0],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:28:59.973", 2],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:29:59.973", 0],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:30:59.973", 0],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:31:59.973", 2],
        ["x","1970-01-19 01:32:59.973", 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
df['changes'] = [np.nan] + [1 if prev == 2 and cur == 0 else np.nan for prev, cur in zip(df['mode'], df['mode'][1:])]
print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
  vehicle                timestamp  mode  changes
0       x  1970-01-19 01:24:59.973     0      NaN
1       x  1970-01-19 01:25:59.973     2      NaN
2       x  1970-01-19 01:26:59.973     2      NaN
3       x  1970-01-19 01:27:59.973     0      1.0
4       x  1970-01-19 01:28:59.973     2      NaN
5       x  1970-01-19 01:29:59.973     0      1.0
6       x  1970-01-19 01:30:59.973     0      NaN
7       x  1970-01-19 01:31:59.973     2      NaN
8       x  1970-01-19 01:32:59.973     0      1.0
```

as desired